# Why is lastModifiedTime in DistributedRegionMXBean is not updated if data is deleted from a region?

Tags: jmx, gemfire, geode

When I add an entry to a region or when a server is created, my region statistics(Eg. lastModifiedTime) gets updated. But when I delete an entry, my region's lastModifiedTime doesn't change.

Is this a bug with Gemfire's statistics?

While creating region, I also set enable-statistics=true

I am using below command with GFSH
show metrics --region=region_name

With code, I have connected using JMX,
final DistributedRegionMXBean rBean = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(mbeanConnection, objName,DistributedRegionMXBean.class);
final long modifiedTime = rBean.getLastModifiedTime();

Basically I am trying get modified regions by specifying a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've just tried this locally with the latest [Apache Geode](https://geode.apache.org/) version and it seems to be failing as well. I've created [GEODE-7764](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-7764) to track the issue.

Cheers.